# ¿Por qué el removeChild me elimina los dos elementos? o ¿Por qué el addEventListener se ejecuta dos veces?

Tags: javascript, html, css

No entiendo porque este código me elimina los dos cuadrados cuando pulso (con el botón derecho) un cuadrado y luego hago lo mismo en el otro y allí pulso eliminar:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("contextmenu", mostrar);
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].addEventListener("contextmenu", mostrar);
function mostrar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.top = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(e.target).top) /*+ parseFloat(getComputedStyle(e.target).height)*/ + "px";
  document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.left = "110px";
  document.querySelector("#Eliminar").addEventListener("click", eliminar);
  function eliminar() {
    document.body.removeChild(e.target);
    document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.p {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}
.d {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: aqua;
}
.p2 {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1 p"></p>
<p class="p2 p"></p>
<div class="d"><p id="Eliminar">Eliminar</p></div>
```

¿Por qué me elimina los dos si yo escribí `document.body.removeChild(e.target);`?, ¿En donde me perdí?.

También he notado un error si pulso con el botón derecho a un cuadrado luego paso al otro, vuelvo a pulsar en el cuadrado de antes y le doy a eliminar me sale un error:

> DOMException: Falied to execute 'removeChild' on "Node": the element is not a child of this node...

Tampoco entiendo porque pasa esto, se supone que me debe eliminar el `e.target`, es decir el elemento al cual por ultima vez he pulsado.

Intentando averiguar que es lo que pasa, me di cuenta de que después de hacer clic derecho en un cuadrado, luego volverlo a hacer en el otro y dándole a eliminar se ejecuta `document.body.removeChild(e.target);` pero el `e.target` era el de antes además se ejecuta de dos veces, no entiendo porque.

En fin, me pueden explicar porque mi código se comporta así? Lo único que quería es que si se le da al eliminar se elimine el elemento en el cual apareció el eliminar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].addEventListener("contextmenu", mostrar);
document.getElementsByTagName("p")[1].addEventListener("contextmenu", mostrar);

 function mostrar(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  objetivo = e.target;
  document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.display = "block";
  document.getElementsByClassName("d")[0].style.top = parseFloat( getComputedStyle( e.target ).top ) /*+ parseFloat( getComputedStyle( e.target ).height)*/ + "px";
  document.getElementsByClassName( "d" )[ 0 ].style.left = "110px";
  document.querySelector( "#Eliminar" ).addEventListener( "click", eliminar );
}

function eliminar() {
  document.body.removeChild( objetivo );
  document.getElementsByClassName( "d" )[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.p {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}
.d {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: aqua;
}
.p2 {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p class="p1 p"></p>
<p class="p2 p"></p>
<div class="d"><p id="Eliminar">Eliminar</p></div>
```

El problema era que que al hacer click sobre la ventana **Eliminar**, cambiaba el **target** a la propia ventana, lo que hice fue guardar en una variable el target del primer click, para usarlo en la función eliminar.

Comment: Lo he probado con mi código y sigue igual, si pulso los dos elemtos de la forma que dije se eliminan los dos, ademas en tu código se ejecuta automaticamente la funcion de eliminar pq le pusiste las llaves(eliminar(e) aunque se soluciona podiendolo en una funcion) y no puede mostrarse el menú para seleccionar eliminar

Comment: Hola @Roberto, detecte el problema, estoy buscando una solución, cuando haces click sobre el cuadro, **e** toma como target el cuadro, el problema es que cuiando haces click sobre **Eliminar**, lo toma como target, y por supuesto, no encuentra hijos... de alguna manera, hay que registrar el primer target.

Comment: @Roberto edite la respuesta y... listo, funciona!!!... me ha dado un poco de trabajo encontrarle la vuelta :)

Comment: Gracias!, aunque aún tengo dudas porque el target se cambia?, es que sigo sin entenderlo.

Comment: @Roberto, es simple, cuando haces click sobre el cuadrado, este pasa a ser el target, el problema surge cuando quieres borrar y haces click sobre la mini ventana de **Eliminar**, al hacerlo, esta pasa a ser el target.